# Why are my CSS animation transitions not being applied to hamburger icon?

Tags: css, animation, transition

I have no idea why the transition is not being applied for an the animation of a hamburger menu.

I have tried to isolate the issue of why the transition is not being applied but I cannot see why.

```css
  @media only screen and (max-width: 763px) {
  .menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu-btn-burger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu-btn-burger::before,
  .menu-btn-burger::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu-btn-burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
  }
  .menu-btn-burger::after {
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  /* ANIMATION */
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
  }
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href=# onclick="openMenu()" class="icon">
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <div class="menu-btn-burger">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</nav>
```

Comment: you have to add `s` to the time of animation(mean second) `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;` (without it it is invalid css)

Comment: Argh thank you so much!